# PHPexcel won't export query result fields

Tags: php, export-to-excel, phpexcel

I am having a bit of a trouble trying to figure out as to where I am going wrong.

I am trying to export an excel (xlsx) file to the browser after populating it with data retrieved from a MySQL query which is thereafter edited in some cases.

This is my current code...

```
if (isset($_POST['export']))
    {
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE status = 'O'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    $filename = "Open_Calls_(". date("Y-m-d") . ").xlsx";
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');  

    $data_exp = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $data_exp = $data_exp->load('../template/Helpdesk - Open Calls.xlsx');

    $data_exp->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setTitle('Open Calls');



    $rowN = 2;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                    $contact1 = $row['contact_no1'];
                    $contact1 = substr_replace($contact1, "-", 3, 0);
                    $contact1 = substr_replace($contact1, "-", 7, 0);

                    if($row['contact_no2'] != "")
                            {
                                    $contact2 = $row['contact_no2'];
                                    $contact2 = substr_replace($contact2, "-", 3, 0);
                                    $contact2 = substr_replace($contact2, "-", 7, 0);
                            }
                    else
                            {
                                    $contact2 = "";
                            }

                    $date1 = new DateTime($row['doc']);
                    $date2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
                    $col = 'A';

                    $data_exp->getActiveSheet()
                            ->setCellValue(A.$rowN, $row['ref_no'])
                            ->setCellValue(B.$rowN, $row['ref_type'])
                            ->setCellValue(C.$rowN, $row['dem_code'])
                            ->setCellValue(D.$rowN, $row['contact_name'])
                            ->setCellValue(E.$rowN, $contact1)
                            ->setCellValue(F.$rowN, $contact2)
                            ->setCellValue(G.$rowN, $row['query_main'])
                            ->setCellValue(H.$rowN, $row['query_sub'])
                            ->setCellValue(I.$rowN, $row['icn_product'])
                            ->setCellValue(J.$rowN, $row['iv_no'])
                            ->setCellValue(K.$rowN, $row['order_no'])
                            ->setCellValue(L.$rowN, $row['section'])
                            ->setCellValue(M.$rowN, $row['action'])
                            ->setCellValue(N.$rowN, $row['logged'])
                            ->setCellValue(O.$rowN, $row['doc'])
                            ->setCellValue(P.$rowN, $row['toc'])
                            ->setCellValue(Q.$rowN, datediff($date1, $date2));

                    $rowN++;
            }

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($data_exp, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();

    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    exit;
    }
```

So I managed to get the file to output into an excel2007 format, but the query result fields are coming out blank.. eg. ->setCellValue(A.$rowN, $row['ref_no']) is returning a blank. More specifically the $row['ref_no'] is returning a blank. All of them in fact.

But if I were to export the query as it comes from a query in a foreach loop without handling the data at all then the excel file is populated perfectly fine. eg...

```
$rowN = 2;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                    {
                            $col = 'A';
                            foreach($row as $cell) 
                                    {
                                            $data_exp->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowN,$cell);
                                            $col++;
                                    }

                            $rowN++;
                    }
```

Why is that?

Could someone be so kind as to let me know where I have gone wrong. Is there something I am missing? Why can I not call the query result fields individually?

I am quite new to php, let alone phpexcel and would appreciate anyone letting me know if I put the wrong headers in or if my format is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that notices about undefined constant A are being generated

`A.$rowN` should be `'A'.$rowN`, etc

but you could simplify it and do...

```
$col = 'A';
$data_exp->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue($col++.$rowN, $row['ref_no'])
    ->setCellValue($col++.$rowN, $row['ref_type'])
    ->setCellValue($col++.$rowN, $row['dem_code'])
    ....
    ->setCellValue($col++.$rowN, datediff($date1, $date2));
```

Comment: I wasn't getting any problems for how I was utilizing the column, apologies for the unused $col = 'A' declaration. I must of left it there from one of my previous attempts. However, this does not solve the problem. On export, the data which comes from the $row[*] is still blank...

Comment: Just a thought, is it because of the ob_end_clean() that my query results are returning no values? If so how can I go about exporting without it because if I exclude the ob_end_clean() then the file becomes corrupt because it tries to export the actual php page (if you open in notepad it shows this).

Comment: The ob_end_clean() should be flushing anything that has been inadvertently sent to php://output before you do the call to save()... assuming you have an ob_start() somewhere earlier in your code... have you tried opening the file in a text editor to see if there's any spurious messages somehow getting in there?

Comment: So I removed the ob_end_clean() and ran the export again. I opened it in word and it says that my variables are undefined. So the ob_end_clean was preventing me from seeing those errors. So my problem is the fact that somehow my variables are being unset...